# can't upgrade or install

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation

I have been having a problem for a few day.

I can't upgrade linux (16.04LTS) anymore and I can't install packages. Here's what I get :
`sudo apt-get update`

> I don't put everything because I am not allowed to post many links
>   E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
>   E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Calculating upgrade... Done
>   The following packages have been kept back:
>     debhelper
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

`sudo apt-get install x11vnc`

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package x11vnc
>   remi@remi-Lenovo-G70-80:~$

Does anybody know what the problem is ?

Comment: ok but the subject points several possible origins, how t know which case is mine ?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`

Comment: *how t know which case is mine* Really?? It's right there in the error message (and if you keep messing with Python, adding PPAs or other things, you will break your system).

Comment: So, the 404 error indicates a website not found, and specifically your error indicates that the repository at `https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6` cannot be found.  All of the answers in the referenced question deal with finding and removing unfound PPAs, by different methods - part of the bigger question is mentioned in JonathanF's PPA - did you remove or disable python3.5?

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, perhaps try removing all non-necessity sources from the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, leaving only the essential ones for the system. By doing so this could possibly fix your issue. Before carrying out this action, I recommend creating a backup just in case you accidently delete something important...

**BACKUP**

You can create a backup simply by running `cp sources.list sources.bak` and if you accidently break something simply either move the copy or copy the copy back to the original by running `cp sources.bak sources.list`...

Hope this helps!!!Let me know

Comment: Hello, Charles Green comment helped me. It works just fine now. Thanks a lot !